# Node.js fast-glob EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, typescript, glob

I am trying to get a list of directories using [`fast-glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-glob#options-3), however there is an unknown number of directories were the user lacks read permissions so `fast-glob` ends up throwing an EACCES and then just hangs. Elevating the user's permissions or lowering the permissions of the glob matches is not an option since this will be in a VS Code extension.

```js
import * as fg from 'fast-glob';
const globIncPaths: string[] = fg.sync(["/usr/lib/**"], {
      onlyDirectories: true,
      suppressErrors: true, // set this to false to raise a EACCES exception
    });
```

In my case `/usr/lib/ssl/private` will cause this to hang.

This can easily be recreated for any dir, e.g.

1. `mkdir -p temp/{public,private}`
2. `chmod -r temp/private`
3. changing `"/usr/lib/**"` from the MWE to `"your/cwd/temp/**"`

Is there a way to suppress the error and continue the glob search simply excluding any matches where I don't have adequate permissions? Am I missing something obvious?

Alternatives to `fast-glob` are also welcome as long as they are not horribly slow/inefficient.

Comment: Does the code you have not do what you want it to do?

Comment: No, the code above will not complete the glob search, it will fail silently and hang indefinitely, it will just not throw an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only reasonable solution that I found is using `glob` with `strict` set to `false`.

```js
import { glob } from 'glob';
const globIncPaths: string[] = [];
for (const i of resIncludePaths) {
  // use '/' to match only directories and not files
  globIncPaths.push(...glob.sync(i + '/', { strict: false }));
}
```

There is a difference in performance for large matches, but there are optimisations to be made, like running `glob` only for the glob patterns that `fast-glob` failed, if performance is that crucial.